# how to enable mod_xsendfile in apache2 in case of using mod_wsgi-express and django

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I'm a newbie in django and lately I've been trying to use apache as my django web server to test mod_xsendfile for a project. My environment: `ubuntu 14.04`, `python 3.4`, `apache2`, `django 1.8`, having `mod_wsgi` installed using `pip`. I also have downloaded and compiled mod_xsendfile on apache2

I have several problems though:.

Problem1: In the documentation provided at [here](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) it states to set mod_xsendfile on and provide a path for it in the virtual host configuration; I searched and noticed the virtual host config takes place in a file named `httpd.conf` and in `ubuntu 14.04` having `apache2` installed it seems that the whole structures has changed so I found no such file.

Problem2: I am using mod_wsgi-express for running my server and it performs all the configurations automatically. I have read the documentations in [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi) and [here](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html) but I couldn't find in any of them being stated where the general configurations (apache configurations to be specific) are pulled from.

**Long story short:** my question being: how can I enable mod_xsendfile considering my environment and the fact that I am using mod_wsgi-express which generates the configs automatically.

**Note:**: I run the server using the following command: `$python manage.py runmodwsgi`

Comment: You would better off asking on the mod_wsgi mailing list. http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/finding-help.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Thanks, I've read your blog and commented my question before. I found nothing on how the runmodwsgi pull out user configuration performed on apache. I think my question is too easy to answer but I am just overwhelmed by the whole new environment to figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Graham Dumpleton here's the solution that worked for me:

I put the following directive into a file named extra.conf:

```
LoadModule xsendfile_module 'usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_xsendfile.so'
XSendFile On
XSendFilePath /tmp/PrivateFiles
```

Then I passed the extra.conf path as an arguement to the --include-file=<> option of modwsgi command as follows:

```
$python manage.py runmodwsg --include-file=/etc/apache2/sites-available/extra.conf
```